# Progess Dialog with fragment inside activity call asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity, fragment

I have a main activity, which has a fragment inside, that calls an `Asynctask`.

Main Activity - The main activity has a `ViewPager` that loads the fragment.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    this.mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            //actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                       //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
```

Fragment - Makes Call to service

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
ServiceHelper srv = new ServiceHelper(getActivity(), "GetHomeImage", postParameters, 2);
    AsyncTask<String, Void, String> request = srv.execute();
return view;
}
}
```

Async Task Class - Show Progressdialog and make requests

```
public class ServiceHelper extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

public ServiceHelper(Context c, String method, HashMap<String, Object> parameters, int requestType){
     context = c;
     this.method = method;
     this.parameters = parameters;
     this.requestType = requestType;
 }

protected void onPreExecute(){   
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Requisição", "Chamando Serviço", true, false);
}

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
do stuff...
}
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
progressDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that the fragment is called, the request is made, but the `Progessdialog` only appears when the fragment is shown.
It's possible to show the `Progressdialog` when the call is made?

Thanks.

Comment: In which part of your Fragment are you making the `ServiceHelper`?

Comment: Post code of the Fragment

Comment: I'm calling the service onCreateView. i added the fragment code above.
The progrees dialog is only appear when the fragment is retuned.

Comment: So when the dialog appear the request is already finished.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple way here is show progress dialog before call to execute AsyncTask. for closing progress dialog you should add a Listener to ServiceHelper and listen it to dismiss dialog on cancel or completion of task. here is code:

```
final Dialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Requisição", "Chamando Serviço", true, false);
ServiceHelper srv = new ServiceHelper(getActivity(), "GetHomeImage", postParameters, 2);
srv.setListener(new ServiceHelperListener() {
    public void onCancel() {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    public void onCompelte() {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
AsyncTask<String, Void, String> request = srv.execute();
```

and ServiceHelper class and Listener:

```
public class ServiceHelper extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private ServiceHelperListener mListener;

public ServiceHelper(Context c, String method, HashMap<String, Object> parameters, int requestType){
    context = c;
    this.method = method;
    this.parameters = parameters;
    this.requestType = requestType;
}

public void setListener(ServiceHelperListener listener) {
    this.mListener = listener;
}

protected void onPreExecute(){
}

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    do stuff...
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onCompelte();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled(String s) {
    super.onCancelled(s);
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onCancel();
    }
}
}

public interface ServiceHelperListener {
    public void onCancel();
    public void onCompelte();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice idea, but the progress dialog only shows up when fragment is finish loading. when the dialog shows, the request is already done.